# Celery Workflow Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'AsyncResult' and 'AsyncResult'

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I am quite novice with celery and its fundamentals, so please forgive my ignorance. I am trying to design a workflow which is as follows:

```
import os
from celery import Celery, group, chord, chain

class CeleryConfig:
    """
    Configuration for Celery
    """
    broker_url = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL','mongodb://localhost:9001/jobs')
    result_backend = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', 'mongodb://localhost:9001/')
    celery_mongodb_backend_settings = {
        "database": "results", 
        "taskmeta_collection": "test",
    }
    enable_utc = True
    timezone = "UTC"
    celery_imports = ('test',)
    task_always_eager = os.environ.get('CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER', False)
    task_eager_propagates = os.environ.get('CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES',False)
    task_serializer = 'json'

celery_app = Celery("test")
celery_app.config_from_object(CeleryConfig)

@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def dummy_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return True

@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def a(self, pagination, *args, **kwargs):
    return pagination[0] + pagination[1]

@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def b(self, pagination, *args, **kwargs):
    return pagination[0] + pagination[1]

@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def workflow(self):
    batch_size = 10
    flow_a = chord(group(a.s((k,batch_size), max_retries=None) for k in range(5)), dummy_task.s())()
    flow_b = chord(group(b.si((k,batch_size), immutable=True, max_retries=None) for k in range(5)), dummy_task.s())()

    r = chain(flow_a, flow_b)()
    return r

task = workflow.apply_async()
```

I use `celery -A test worker -l info` to run the celery worker. When I try to execute the above script I get the following error:

```
[2018-07-20 22:51:11,221: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task test.workflow[aaea266e-bd5a-4414-a42f-83ccb5d16145] raised unexpected: TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'AsyncResult' and 'AsyncResult'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sohaibfarooqi/projects/code/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 382, in trace_task
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sohaibfarooqi/projects/code/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 641, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sohaibfarooqi/projects/code/test.py", line 42, in workflow
     r = chain(flow_a, flow_b)()
 File "/Users/sohaibfarooqi/projects/code/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 784, in __new__
     return reduce(operator.or_, tasks)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'AsyncResult' and 'AsyncResult'
```

Although this error is raised, tasks executes fine. Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong and point me in right direction?

**Celery Version:** 4.2.0

**Python Version:** 3.5.0

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error for until I did something like

chain(task1.si(param1,param2), task2.si(paramX))()

If you use "si" in place of "s" its immutable and the result of the first is not passed to the next task.

more on this http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#immutability